# Show if $M$ is free of rank $n$ as $R$-module, then $M/IM$ is free of rank $n$ as $R/I$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $I \subset R $ a two-sided ideal and $M$ an $R$-module with

$$IM = \{ \sum r_i x_i \mid r_i \in I, x_i \in M \}. $$

Show that if the $R$-module $M$ is free of rank $n$ then $M/IM$ is also an $R/I$ free module of rank $n$. I have shown that $IM$ is an $R$-submodule of $M$ and an $R/I$ module but i do not know how to approach this question. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is $M/IM$ a submodule of $M?$ It is an $R/I$-module since it's annihilated by $I.$ You might want to check what happens to the generators of $M$ on passage to the quotient $M/IM.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof that $M/IM$ is a submodule of $M$ is surely wrong. Take $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $M/IM=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ that doesn't even embed in $M$.

Saying that $M$ is a free module of rank $n$ is the same as saying that $M\cong R^n$ and it's not restrictive to take $M=R^n$. Now $IR^n=I^n$ and
$$
M/IM=R^n/I^n\cong(R/I)^n
$$
as $R$-modules via the map
$$
(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)+I^n\mapsto(x_1+I,x_2+I,\dots,x_n+I)
$$
This is also an isomorphism of $R/I$-modules, as you can verify.

Comment: oh yes i made a typo, it was supposed to be $IM$ as a submodule instead.